# What do you think of the new Yahoo Mail UI? Is it a good or bad UI?

Tags: email

Recently Yahoo changed the UI of the Yahoo Mail service. I am curious what you think about it?

There's one "retro" function - keyboard shortcuts :-)

- and what is really interesting about them I started using some
- eventhough never used keyboard shortcuts in mail apps before

Here's a screenshot!

[image]

Comment: I wouldn't call keyboard shortcuts retro, I think of them as absolutely essential if you want to use a site effectively.

Comment: I can't mention any other web mail service which has built in keyboard shortcuts

Comment: Let's take this discussion to [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/389/user-experience). If you want to zero in on some specific aspect of the new interface (keyboard shortcuts?), feel free to ask another question that follows the guidelines in the [FAQ](http://ux.stackexchange.com/faq).

Comment: Although I don't want to close the question, I think the grammar police need to make an arrest.  If the question was, "How important are keyboard shortcuts?  Example: Y! Mail" I would have been less confused about the question.  (Short answer: Keyboard Shortcuts are essential to giving power users a sense of extra power."

Answer (score 4):

I might miss some intended humor here, but it does look like Gmail and Gmail has very good keyboard shortcuts.

Answer (score 3):

It looks great! Much better than it did. I would also agree that they are trending toward the Gmail look, which is a good thing for users who do not wish to move away from Yahoo!.

Answer (score 2):

Am i missing something here? This screenshot is actually the old(er) UI for Yahoo mail. They've updated it (again) within the last month or two.